# How to append a list to a list of lists with 2 while loops

Tags: python, list, while-loop

I made a simpler version of the code I'm working on below. When I print the biglist list at the bottom of the code, I expected to see 10 iterations of the same data in the list:

```
new_result = True 
countlist = 0
countlist2 = 2
countlist3 = 3
biglist = []

while new_result:
    if countlist == 10:
        new_result = False
    else:
        new_result = True
    while countlist2 < 100:
        timestwo = countlist2 * 2
        countlist2 += 2
        timesthree = countlist3 * 3
        countlist3 += 3
        biglist.append([timestwo,timesthree])
    countlist += 1

countlist2 = 2
countlist3 = 3


print(biglist)
```

My questions are:

1. Can someone explain to me why only 1 iteration of the numbers data is showing in the list?
2. Where in the code does the list get wiped out again?
3. Is there a way to just add the list to the list of lists to get 10 iterations of the data?

Data Returned:

`[[4, 9], [8, 18], [12, 27], [16, 36], [20, 45], [24, 54], [28, 63], [32, 72], [36, 81], [40, 90], [44, 99], [48, 108], [52, 117], [56, 126], [60, 135], [64, 144], [68, 153], [72, 162], [76, 171], [80, 180], [84, 189], [88, 198], [92, 207], [96, 216], [100, 225], [104, 234], [108, 243], [112, 252], [116, 261], [120, 270], [124, 279], [128, 288], [132, 297], [136, 306], [140, 315], [144, 324], [148, 333], [152, 342], [156, 351], [160, 360], [164, 369], [168, 378], [172, 387], [176, 396], [180, 405], [184, 414], [188, 423], [192, 432], [196, 441]]`

Expected 10 iterations of the same data in the list, instead I only got 1 iteration.

Comment: Can you clarify by showing expected output? Also, is there a particular reason why you (apparently) feel the need to use 2 while loops?

Comment: Please read about [how to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). You can also use [Python Tutor](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit) to run your code line-by-line. Lastly, after debugging your code, create a [mre] of a ***specific*** problem you found in the process and ask about that

Comment: You need to reset `countlist2` and `countlist3` back to 2 and 3 in the first while loop. Currently you are doing so outside the first while loop.

Comment: After the first iteration of the outer loop, `countlist2` will be greater than 100. The next iteration, the inner loop will not execute at all... Did you meant to reset `countlist2` inside the loop?

Comment: @DarkKnight in my actual code, I have a url that contains an option for pagination, so the first while loop cycles to the first page, and the second while loop picks out the data I need from a json response, then puts it into a list, then the first while loop goes to the 2nd page, pulls the data again etc. I expected there to be 10 sets of the data I put at the bottom of the post.

Comment: This sounds unrelated to the code you presented. A more relevant [mre] will be better to help you solve the real problem (unless of course the indentation is actually your real problem as well...)

Comment: The reset of `countlist2` and `countlist3` needs to be tabbed in one level so that at the end of the outer while loop they are reset for the next iteration. As it is now, `countlist2` is always > 100 after the first iteration of the outer loop

Comment: @It_is_Chris this is exactly what I needed, I indented them both and i'm now getting 10 iterations in the biglist, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

###### Current problem

After the first iteration of the outer `while` loop, you keep incrementing `countlist2` until the condition of the inner `while` loop stops from holding. At the next iteration (and all subsequent iterations) of the outer `while` loop, the condition will not hold to begin with and the inner `while` loop will not execute.

###### Solution

Initiate the relevant variables ***inside*** the loop:

```py
new_result = True 
countlist = 0
biglist = []

while new_result:
    if countlist == 10:
        new_result = False
    else:
        new_result = True
    countlist2 = 2
    countlist3 = 3
    while countlist2 < 100:
        timestwo = countlist2 * 2
        countlist2 += 2
        timesthree = countlist3 * 3
        countlist3 += 3
        biglist.append([timestwo,timesthree])
    countlist += 1

print(biglist)
```

###### Improvements

To avoid such problems, use `for` loops when the range of iteration is pre-determined:

```py
biglist = []
for _ in range(10):
    countlist3 = 3
    for countlist2 in range(2, 100, 2):
        timestwo = countlist2 * 2
        timesthree = countlist3 * 3
        countlist3 += 3
        biglist.append([timestwo,timesthree])

print(biglist)
```

Or using [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```py
biglist = []
for _ in range(10):
    for i, j in zip(range(2, 100, 2), range(3, 100, 3)):
        timestwo = i * 2
        timesthree = j * 3
        biglist.append([timestwo,timesthree])

print(biglist)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the output shown in the question repeated 10 times then:

```
output = []

for _ in range(10):
    for x in range(4, 200, 4):
        output.append([x, x//4*9])

print(output)
```